# Vi/vim copy text from block that passes a symbol

Tags: vim

Assuming that I have a block of text like the picture attached, is there a vim command that would enable me to copy all the text from each line that goes to the left or to the right of the "=" sign for example? The use here is to not spend time having to manually rewrite all of them or copy the block of text then trim away the text unnecessary, but instead copy what is directly wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would simply…

- yank the whole block to a named register:

  ```
  "ayip
  ```
- put it somewhere:

  ```
  "ap
  ```
- remove the right side of each assignment:

  ```
  :'[,']normal! ^ElD
  ```
- put another copy of the initial block somewhere else:

  ```
  "ap
  ```
- remove the left side of each assignment:

  ```
  :'[,']normal! $Bhd0
  ```

but there are so many ways to approach that problem, even without knowing how you want to use each side of the assignments…